# Best Practice Way to Bind Clicks to Multiple Elements with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I've got a web-app that can have about 20 different option buttons on it, represented by spans using jQuery UI Icons.  Some of these options can be used up to maybe 200 times.  These options are things like add, edit, delete, reorder items on the page.  All are contained within a container DIV.

Essentially, there is a container DIV, with its own set of options.  Within that are any number of section DIVs, with their own set of options.  Finally, within each section there are panel DIVs, with their options also (could be >100 panels per section).  Due to the nature of the app, sections and panels will be added and removed from the container during its use.

When any of these options are clicked, I want to add an "active" class to highlight it, carry out some code, depending on which option was selected, and remove the active code when finished.  None of this is particularly difficult so far, but I'm looking for the most efficient and best practice way to handle the event binding(s) in JQuery.

Example HTML (for the purposes of example, this has been simplified, and some JQuery classes may be mis-spelt)...

```
<div id='container'>
    <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick optionButton addSection'></span>
    <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-gear optionButton editContainer'></span>

    <div>...Overall Container Contents Here...</div>

    <div id='section_1' class='section'>
        <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-gear optionButton editSection'></span>
        <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick optionButton deleteSection'></span>
        <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n optionButton moveUpSection'></span>
        <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s optionButton moveDownSection'></span>
        <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick optionButton addContent'></span>
        
        <div>...Section 1 Contents Here...</div>

        <div id='panel_1' class='panel'>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-gear optionButton editPanel'></span>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick optionButton deletePanel'></span>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n optionButton moveUpPanel'></span>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s optionButton moveDownPanel'></span>

            <div>...Panel 1 Contents Here...</div>
        </div>

        <div id='panel_2' class='panel'>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-gear optionButton editPanel'></span>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick optionButton deletePanel'></span>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n optionButton moveUpPanel'></span>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s optionButton moveDownPanel'></span>

            <div>...Panel 2 Contents Here...</div>
        </div>

        .
        .
        .
        (could be 150 panels here)
    </div>

    <div id='section_2' class='section'>
        <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-gear optionButton editSection'></span>
        <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick optionButton deleteSection'></span>
        <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n optionButton moveUpSection'></span>
        <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s optionButton moveDownSection'></span>
        <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick optionButton addContent'></span>
        
        <div>...Section 2 Contents Here...</div>

        <div id='panel_151' class='panel'>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-gear optionButton editPanel'></span>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick optionButton deletePanel'></span>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n optionButton moveUpPanel'></span>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s optionButton moveDownPanel'></span>

            <div>...Panel 151 Contents Here...</div>
        </div>

        <div id='panel_152' class='panel'>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-gear optionButton editPanel'></span>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick optionButton deletePanel'></span>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n optionButton moveUpPanel'></span>
            <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s optionButton moveDownPanel'></span>

            <div>...Panel 152 Contents Here...</div>
        </div>

        .
        .
        .
        (could be another 150 panels here)
    </div>

    .
    .
    .
    (could be multiple sections here)
</div>
```

This is the broad layout, and I need to bind click events to anything with an `optionButton` class.  At present I'm using this...

```
$('#container').on('click', '.optionButton:not(".ui-state-disabled")', function(e) {
    var $tgt = $(this);
    $tgt.addClass("ui-state-active")

    if($tgt).hasClass('addSection') {
        // code for addSection button
    }

    if($tgt).hasClass('editContainer') {
        // code for editContainer button
    }

    ...and so on for all 20 buttons...

    $tgt.removeClass("ui-state-active")
});
```

Is this the best way to go about it?

Or, would it be considered OK to put a click bind on each button style?  (that is, 20 calls to the `on()` function)

The problem of a single bind is that the code gets quite cumbersome and hard to follow quite quickly, but it does fit it all under one common bind quite nicely.

Other thoughts I've considered...

- Immediately branch off to a function call in the single bind so that it just consists of a list of `if($tgt.hasClass('thisClass')) { doThisFunction($tgt); }`
- Put a custom element inside of each option button span.  For example `thisOption='editContent'`.  Then, having a function called `editContent` so that I could perhaps use something like `eval( $tgt.prop('thisOption') + '(' + $tgt + ')' );` to automatically have the span control the function it calls when its clicked on.  As long as each "thisOption" value had a related function, the overall bind would only need a couple of lines of code in its function
- I've looked into Custom Events in JQuery, and have an overall bind trigger them using `.trigger()`, but I don't think this would be any different than having 20 click binds

Any advice on the best way to accomplish this would be very welcome (or any alternatives if I'm thinking about this the wrong way).  I'm building up this project gradually and taking care to be as efficient as I can at each step.  If I've not explained this very well, I do apologise, and I'll have another go.

Comment: Better is to use delegation especially to avoid some kind of memory leak on some browser if you manipulate DOM too often and use a kind of web application (not reloading page).

Comment: I had not heard of the SE code review until you posted this - looks very useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a much better practice to have the 20 `.on()` delegates because otherwise on each click event the entire logic would be executed to check what is the precise target. Otherwise only the specific logic for the target would be executed. You are essentially repeating parts of the delegate functionality of the `on()` letting it delegate to an non-specific selector and then making it specific within your own function.

Comment: Yes, I was fearful that having approximately 20 binds all listening for clicks in the same DIV might be considered a burden on the browser. Not knowing the nuts and bolts of what is actually happening has led to pages of notes.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a common logic for all the elements, then use a common bind for all elements. If you don't have a common logic then it will be better to use different binds.

Comment: That's given me an alternate way of thinking about it, thank you.  I could group all of the similar options into one bind, so rather than one big bind or twenty small ones, I could have five manageable ones.  For example - "delete" type options into one bind if their code is similar enough.  Likewise with "edit" and "reorder".  Thank you.